# How to define channels and Levels in monolog logging in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way that i can define my custom levels in monolog in symfony2.

I i do this

`$logger->err('An error occurred');`

Then in the database i have this added.

The channel is `app` and level is `500`

Is there any way to do this

```
$logger->log("message",(channel),(level)
$logger->log("Object with is 212 deleted",'DELETE',NORMAL);
```

So that i can have separate things in database for reporting and viewing

Answer (score 13):

With version 2.4 and up (beware, the release cycle of the MonologBundle is not syncronized with symfony anymore) of the MonologBundle, you can now define new channels very simple via configuration, without defining services.

```
monolog:
    channels: ["my_channel"]
```

Now simply get the automatically created logger for the new channel in your controller:

```
$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.my_channel');
$logger->info('somelogcontent');
```

The message level is defined trough the use of the appropriate method. Take a look into the [`LoggerInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php) to see all logging methods (which are indeed implemented by monolog). Here some levels to be mentioned:

```
$logger->info('Info message for interesting things');
$logger->warning('Some application warnings, but the application works');
$logger->error('Error which can influence the application flow/output');
```

---

I know old question, but this new feature from the `MonologBundle` `~2.4` should be mentioned.

Comment: It is worth looking at PSR-3 for a reference on how the interface is implemented, what is the hierarchy of the log levels https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-3-logger-interface.md

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Monolog documentation](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md), channels are tied to loggers, basically the logger's name is your channel. That means you can't specify another channel in a given logger but you can create new loggers with different channels.

Levels are just numbers and [constants](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L77), so you can create your own. With the right formatter, you'll get the string corresponding to your custom level.

Comment: I understand what ur saying about 60% But as i am new to Symfony can usu just give me small code example where i can extend Logger class for new level